# Spy on a function that returns an observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs

I'm testing an Angular 4 component with a function that makes a HTTP request (returning an observable) and then calls another function in the observables subscribe method. I want to test that the function in the subscribe is being called correctly. The component looks like this:

```
logIn(): void {
  this.loginService.logIn(user)
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
  })
}
```

I've mocked the service in the component's spec:

```
loginServiceStub = {
  logIn(user: User) {
    return Observable.of(true)
  },
}
```

And I've attached a spy to the router and the login service to know if they have been called:

```
const logInSpy = spyOn(loginService, 'logIn')
const navigateByUrlSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl')
```

When calling the components login method, the logInSpy is being called but the navigateByUrlSpy is not and the subscribe method is not being run. How should I set up the mock logIn to get this working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following

**Stub:**

```
loginServiceStub = {
  logIn: jasmine.createSpy('logIn').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true))
}
```

**In the test:**

```
const navigateByUrlSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl').and.callThrough();
```